# Multithreading to read a small number of files on Android?

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading

I'm reading a lot of answers on SO that it's best not to use multithreading when attempting to read a number of files. I understand the bottleneck is in the I/O rather than the cpu.

Is this still true for Android? What if I only plan to read 10-20 json config files?

Comment: Have you proven that there is a need for multi-threading?

Comment: If it's true in general, why wouldn't it be then for Android too?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Not completely. Just considering options. There's a bottleneck somewhere. Wanted to know if multithreading could be used for something like this.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: I'm not sure how the disk is read on an Android device vs a computer.